# Using classes with different namespaces in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, class, external, laravel-8

I am trying to use a library of classes within Laravel 8. I am having difficulty getting the classes to load correctly. I created a new folder within the App folder called DigiSigner, which is the external library's namespace.

```
App\DigiSigner
  DigiSignerClient.php
  \libs
    BaseRequest.php
    Branding.php
    ClassLoader.php
    Config.php
    Curler.php
    DigiSignerException.php
    DigiSignerResponse.php
    Document.php
    DocumentField.php
    DocumentFields.php
    ExistingField.php
    ExportObject.php
    Field.php
    SignatureRequest.php
    Signer.php
```

I created a controller that looks like this

```php
class SignPDFController extends Controller
{
    public function getPDF()
    {
        $client = new DigiSignerClient('client_key');
        $request = new SignatureRequest;
        $request->setEmbedded(true);
        $request->setSendEmails(false);

        $template = Document::withID('document_id');
        $template->setTitle('Site Title');
        $request->addDocument($template);

        $signer = new Signer('user@email.com');
        $signer->setRole('Signer 1');
        $template->addSigner($signer);

        $initials = new ExistingField('key');
        $initials->setContent('VS');
        $signer->addExistingField($initials);

        $response = $client->sendSignatureRequest($request);

        foreach ($response->getDocuments() as $document) {
            foreach ($document->getSigners() as $signer) {
                $signDocumentUrl = $signer->getSignDocumentUrl();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `DigiSignerClient` and the `SignatureRequest` classes seem to load fine, but the `SignatureRequest` needs to load the `ExportObject` class to extend it.

```php
namespace App\DigiSigner;

use App\DigiSigner\libs\ExportObject;

class SignatureRequest extends ExportObject {
```

I end up with an error like the following.

> Error Class 'App\DigiSigner\libs\ExportObject' not found

Namespaces and use are a little fuzzy for me. If someone can point me in the right direction, I would be delighted.

Comment: what namespace is declared in the `ExportObject` file?

Comment: If namespaces are created properly, there should be no need for a `use` statement as those two classes should be in the same namespace.

Comment: The ExportOjbect has namespace App\DigiSigner;

Answer (score 1):

I believe I figured it out. All the files in the subdirectory needed the namespace changed to App\DigiSigner\libs.

Comment: Good you've found the answer yourself. If namespaces are a bit fuzzy, as it was for me once, you could read this php documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Answer (score 0):

Check ExportObject.php namespace.